# getting values and assigning them to a hidden field

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function that is suppose to take a value from a field in a form and assign it to a hidden field when its called. for some reason its not working and I cant give you more details on why its not working simply because javascript doesnt really tell you much about whats wrong.

```
function clickChange(stype){

    if(stype == '1'){
        var fValue = document.getElementById('checkB1').value;
        if(fCatValue == 0){
            fCatValue = fValue;
        }else{
            fCatValue = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('cat_1').value = fCatValue;
    }elseif(stype == '2'){
        var sValue = document.getElementById('checkB2').value;
        if(sCatValue == 0){
            sCatValue = sValue;
        }else{
            sCatValue = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('cat_2').value = sCatValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, let's take it step by step. for starters, if this code is verbatim - you need to put a space in your else if (stype == '2') statement. Also, the single quotes aren't necessary unless it's a string or character you're looking at.

Comment: probably can tell you more if i could see a little bit about what your html looks like as well if all these answers weren't helpful.

Comment: Hey terrance, sorry I got a bit into the problem so I forgot to choose the answer, and now I cant find the answer that was right. I simply had to replace `elseif` with `else if` ... got a bit confused between php and js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the values to integer, or treat them as a string:

either:

```
var fValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('checkB1').value)
        if(fCatValue == 0){....
```

or

```
var fValue = document.getElementById('checkB1').value;
        if(fCatValue =='0'){...
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Because of the placement of your declaration of the variable sCatValue it looks like sCatValue goes out of scope (or doesn't get declared at all).</s>It would probably be easier on you if you declare all of your function scoped variables at the beginning of your function and cut down on the number of nested if statements.

I'd also recommend you use [self explanatory  variable names](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GoodVariableNames) to cut down on confusing yourself. Also I'd recommend walking through your code with the use of a javascript debugger like firebug or ie 9's built in one. (surprising I know). And using  [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) to help out with the common rules.

I found some other bugs and cleaned things up a bit and this is what I got

```
function clickChange(stype) {

    //declared at the start so no scope undefined issues
    var sValue = document.getElementById('checkB2').value;
    var fValue = document.getElementById('checkB1').value;

    //changed the comparision op from == to ===
    //in javascript '===' throws false if the types compared are not the 
    //same otherwise it attemps to preform implicit casting for you
    if (stype === '1') {

        //parsing to insure that the types are matching
        //the 10 is a radix param. It insures your number is formatted as a decimal
        if (parseInt(fCatValue,10)=== 0) {
            fCatValue = fValue;
        } else {
            fCatValue = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('cat_1').value = fCatValue;
    } else if (stype === '2') {
        if (parseInt(sCatValue,10)=== 0) {
            sCatValue = sValue;
        } else {
            sCatValue = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('cat_2').value = sCatValue;
    }
}
```